# Missing nsmb.conf file

Tags: mojave, filesystem, smb

I'm looking for the `nsmb.conf` file to try some different settings to troubleshoot network connectivity issues.  I'm on Mac OS Mojave.  I cannot find that file in `/etc/nsmb.conf` or `~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf`.  Those are the only two locations described in the manual page (http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/nsmb.conf/).

There is an `/etc/smb.conf` file.  What is the difference between an `nsmb.conf` file and `smb.conf` file?

Comment: I foud one /usr/share/man/man5/nsmb.conf.5

Comment: This is the mran page, e.g. the documentation, not the actual file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the file via commandline/Terminal. It does not exist by default.

```
sudo touch /etc/nsmb.conf
```

The **smb**.conf file is most likely carried over from updating older versions of macOS. It’s not used anymore in Mojave.

The terminal command above is the global location for the config file, if you want to set config options for specific users, see the following URL. The link also contains additional info about SMB config.

https://www.flyweb.at/blog/network/1004/samba-fun-with-osx/

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the file is not there by default.